# How to use getAssets in a class that extends CCLayer

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, cclayer

I have a class that extends `CCLayer`. I have to get a text file from assets folder. But i couldn't use `getAssets()` in this class. How can i use `getAssets()` in a class that extends `CCLayer`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the answer...

```
Context context = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().getApplicationContext();
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("abc.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

when you create a method in your class, use:

```
private void abc (Context context){
    context.getAssets();
}
```

and when you call this method, you must put you context into method:

```
yourclass.abc(getBaseContext());
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `getBaseContext()` when i tried to use that, it gave me error :(

Comment: try new yourclass.abc(your_activity.this) or new yourclass.abc(getapplicationcontext()) .
you could post detail your class

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in context to the class to use it. If its your custom class, pass it in the constructor and then hold on it and use it.